# Change TextView value in ListView without onClickListener Android

Tags: android, listview, textview

In the layout I'm using for my custom adapter that I use to display my listview, there is a TextView. I would like to modify the value of this textview programmatically, but without clicking on anything. The new value is obtained on the main activity and is updated every 1s from a bound service. Is there a way to access the setText method of a textview in a specific row in a listview? Should I use a listener in the custom adapter to update the value?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes You can do it all you need to do is datasource that is attached to the listView 
e.g. ArrayList of data from where you show the initial data to the list item.

You need to update it when you got data from the service and after datasource is updated you just need to call the `notifiydatasetChanged` method

e.g. `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

it will refresh your list with the updated data. In your case Textview text.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your conditional logic inside `getView()` of your adapter to modify the `TextView`. For example , if you want to change the `TextView` when the listview item position is 2 , inside your getView() have something like

```
if(position==2){
//modify your textview as per requirement
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the code:
So pretend that you already created a ListView Adapter then

if you want to edit your list view just put this code and remember dont forget to put **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();**

> ```
>       //The Count of your array position    // your getter and setter
> data.set(datacount , new URLKeylistData(*Your parameter that show in UI*)
> adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // this is important dont miss
> List_lv.setAdapter(new URLKeyAdapter(getBaseContext(), data)); //set again your adapter
> ```

Comment: Great ! I didn't know this method, so useful! Thanks a lot